# Base class for outlook item

Tags: outlook, mapi, outlook-object-model

I am new to Outlook object model. I want to trap some events like selectionchange events etc. What I found that in the selection object it returns the system.object. I have to do type checking for each item type. Not sure if there is any better way to do this.

I don't want to do type checking every time.

Ashwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no base class for outlook message item

Check this out http://outlookitemwrapper.codeplex.com/.

You can use this wrapper. Hope this would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is there any alternative way as well other than this wrapper - Ashwin

Answer (score 0):

Why not use late binding and check the Class property? Every Outlook object exposes it.

Comment: Won't that require type checking? I do not want to do type checking for each class. is there any sample code available?

Comment: How late binding would work if there is no base class with different message properties & methods. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.class.aspx Class returns enum. I can use the 'is' operation for type checking. That is not the issue. I want to support different message types, problem is I do not want long if-else condition to check the message type.

Comment: Declare the item as a generic object and use GetType() to invoke any method or property.